# Unable to link FFMpeg libraries in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, ffmpeg, libavcodec, avcodec

I have been trying to link the FFMPEG static libraries to Visual studio 2012 in c++ environment. But i get the following error.

- Error    1   error LNK1104: cannot open file
  'avcodec.lib'    C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\LINK   ConsoleApplication5

my lib files were located in C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ExtLib\lib

The compile seems to be fine. The command line is

- /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t
  /I"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ExtLib\include"
  /Zi /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D
  "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt
  /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MTd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo
  /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.pch"

The main issue seems to be at the linking stage where I have just not been able to get VS2012 to find my ffmpeg .lib files

The linker command line is below:

- /OUT:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exe"
  /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.pdb"
  /DYNAMICBASE "avcodec.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib"
  "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib"
  "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"
  /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:NOREF /INCREMENTAL
  /PGD:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.pgd"
  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
  /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exe.intermediate.manifest"
  /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO
  /LIBPATH:"/LIBPATH:C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ExtLib\lib"
  /TLBID:1

I cant figure out why the linker cant locate my ffmpeg lib files even though they are physically located in the /LIBPATH area - c:...\vs12...\ExtLib\lib

Answer (score 0):

Your LIBPATH doesn't look correct - it should be quoted like this if the path contains spaces:

`/LIBPATH:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ExtLib\lib"`

You seem to have an additional LIBPATH inside the quotes (in asterisks below)

`/LIBPATH:"**/LIBPATH:**C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ExtLib\lib"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! it helped in pulling out the problems. The most important step is to add the absolute path of lib files in the additional dependencies option. I have now made a comprehensive and detailed report of what steps are to be followed to get it ported. If some one needed, please find it here. [link] (http://ramu492.blogspot.in/2013/06/porting-ffmpeg-on-to-winodws7-and.html)